# Inverse prediction with a polynomial model

Tags: r, regression, prediction

I've a polynomial model for a linear, univariate regression and I've to predict *x* from *y* for a new dataset.
The model is something like

```
f22<- lm(y~I(x^2.0) + I(x^3.0) + I(x^0.5))
```

I use this model in a quite narrow range of *x*, where the model is monotone.
I think I cannot use the function *predict.lm*... any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: A quick way but maybe not the best is to collect samples from x and y and then fit a model where the input is y

Comment: @Donbeo No, that's a different model (different assumptions regarding the error-term).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution based on `uniroot`:

```
#some data
x <- 1:100
set.seed(42)
y <- 1.8*x^2 - 0.015*x^3 + 0.4*x^0.5 + rnorm(100)
plot(y~x)

#fitting the model
f22<- lm(y~I(x^2.0) + I(x^3.0) + I(x^0.5), data=data.frame(x, y))
f22

lines(x, predict(f22))
```

[image: resulting plot]

```
#function to pass to uniroot for inverse prediction
ynew <- 2000 + (1:10)*100 
fun <- function(x1, y1, mod) {
  predict(mod, newdata=data.frame(x=x1)) - y1
}    
#note how the interval is specified
xpred <- sapply(ynew, function(z) uniroot(fun, interval=c(20, 70), mod=f22, y1=z)$root)
#[1] 42.46892 43.86588 45.27242 46.69238 48.12992 49.58967 51.07714 52.59857 54.16165 55.77589

#check if it worked
predict(f22, newdata=data.frame(x=xpred))
#       1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10 
#2100.000 2200.000 2300.000 2400.001 2500.002 2599.999 2700.000 2800.000 2900.000 3000.000
```